# runnun multiple functions on webpage

Tags: php

I have an webpage on which i want to display 2 separate tables with content from the same database. How do i run separate functions on a webpage and display 2 different results?

The code i have so far:
the second query that i want to run is in it as query2, but this doesn`t work....

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "776";   
$wachtwoord = "776";  
$database = "kse001_h5mh"; 
$query = "SELECT beschrijving FROM supermarkt WHERE soort = 'komkommertest'";  //de SQL-query
 $resultaat = ""; // hierin wordt het resultaat van de query opgeslagen

 if (!$db = mysql_connect($server, $user, $wachtwoord)){ // probeert de verbinding te maken
 $melding = "<h2>Verbinding maken met databaseserver is mislukt!</h2>";
 }
  else{
 $melding = "<h2>Verbinding maken met databaseserver is tot stand gebracht!</h2>";

         if(!mysql_select_db($database)){  // open de gewenste database
            $melding .= "...maar de database \"$database\" kon niet worden gevonden!";
            } else {
        $melding .= "en de database \"$database\" is geselecteerd!";

                if(!$resultaat = mysql_query($query, $db)){
                 $melding .= "<br />...maar de query \"$query\" kon niet worden uitgevoerd!";
               } else {
        $melding .="<br />De query \"$query\" is met succes uitgevoerd!";
                    }
    }

$query2 = "SELECT beschrijving FROM supermarkt WHERE soort = 'hamburger'";  //de SQL-query
 $resultaat2 = ""; // hierin wordt het resultaat van de query opgeslagen

 if (!$db = mysql_connect($server, $user, $wachtwoord)){ // probeert de verbinding te maken
 $melding = "<h2>Verbinding maken met databaseserver is mislukt!</h2>";
 } else {
          $melding = "<h2>Verbinding maken met databaseserver is tot stand gebracht!</h2>";

         if(!mysql_select_db($database)){  // open de gewenste database
           $melding .= "...maar de database \"$database\" kon niet worden gevonden!";
         } else {
             $melding .= "en de database \"$database\" is geselecteerd!";

                 if(!$resultaat2 = mysql_query($query, $db)){
        $melding .= "<br />...maar de query \"$query\" kon niet worden uitgevoerd!";
                } else {
                     $melding .="<br />De query \"$query\" is met succes uitgevoerd!";
                   }
    }
    mysql_close($db); //database afsluiten
 ?>
   </head>
<body>
<?php echo $melding; ?>
<hr />
<?php
while(list($bescrijving) = mysql_fetch_row($resultaat))
{
echo "$bescrijving is geboren op <br />";
}
?>

<?php
while(list($bescrijving) = mysql_fetch_row($resultaat2))
{
echo "$bescrijving is geboren op <br />";
}
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Any errors? Please post the error message which you get or explain what happens.

Answer (score 1):

First problem, stop using mysql_ functions family... this kind of function was deprecated and will stop work soon or just don't run appropriately.

You should change to PDO family functions try this:

```
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kse001_h5mh', '776', '776');
 $query1 = $dbh->query("SELECT beschrijving FROM supermarkt WHERE soort = 'komkommertest'");
 $query1->fetchAll(); // bring the result

 $query2 = $dbh->query("SELECT beschrijving FROM supermarkt WHERE soort = 'hamburger'");
 $query2->fetchAll(); // bring the result
```

This should work.

Comment: thank you, but how do i call the results on the webpage itself now? now i get this error:Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/kse001/domains/kseinformatica.nl/public_html/supermarkt/ophalen.php on line 24

Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/kse001/domains/kseinformatica.nl/public_html/supermarkt/ophalen.php on line 31

Comment: You don't use mysql_fetch_row to feed the query. Just with fetchAll you can do it. fetchAll will return a collection with the results of the query, so $result = $query1->fetchAll(); will bring your list, you can cast it to array to work better and show on page just as you'r doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 process of your script using the [pcntl-fork function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php).

You can also try to use [ob_flush function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) to send the output buffer between your 2 database requests.

In your case, I think it's a better option to load data in AJAX if it's possible.